# how to install drivers or software for startek fm 220 u finger print scanner in ubuntu 20.04.2?

Tags: 20.04, lts, fingerprint-reader

if there is a ppa or something, please let me know.

Do I need to install wine and then install the windows drivers?

Comment: Windows drivers simply won't work. Wine cannot handle drivers.

Comment: ohh...okay, thank you for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Required driver from Manufacturer should be downloaded for given hardware platform and Operating-system. If it is not available, then it will not be possible.